# Сортировка строк двумерного динамического массива

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка, указатели, qsort

Не могу понять почему не работает qsort для строк динамического двумерного массива:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
     return *(int*)a - *(int*)b;
 }

int** array_sort(int** array,int width)
{
    for(int i=0;i<width;i++)
    {
     qsort(array[i],array[i][0],sizeof(int),cmp);
    }
}
```

Первый элемент каждой строки массива хранит кол-во элементов в этой строке, поэтому сортировать мне надо начиная с array[i][1].

Comment: А какой массив и как вы передаете - это раз, и второе - width - это вообще-то ширина :), т.е. по логике число столбцов (к корректности кода не относится). Ну, а первым тогда надо передавать аргумент `&array[i][1]`.

Comment: @Harry спасибо &array[i][1] сработал, не додумался ссылку передавать

Comment: Это не ссылка, а адрес элемента `array[i][1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, в которой показано 1) как вызвать функцию `qsort` для каждого динамически выделенного под-массива, и 2) как написать функцию сравнения для сортировки.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int cmp( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    int left  = *( const int * )a;
    int right = *( const int * )b;

    return ( right < left ) - ( left < right );
}

int main( void )
{
    const int N = 10;
    int **a = malloc( N * sizeof( int * ) );

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = malloc( ( i + 2 ) * sizeof( int ) );
        a[i][0] = i + 1;

        for ( int j = 0; j < a[i][0]; j++ ) a[i][j+1] = rand() % ( N * N );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < a[i][0]; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j +1] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        qsort( a[i] + 1, a[i][0], sizeof( int ), cmp );
    }        

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < a[i][0]; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j+1] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) free( a[i] );
    free( a );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль, к примеру, может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
47 
48 42 
34 10 24 
28 89 72 97 
12 71 81 60 2 
8 87 48 13 27 74 
58 19 44 54 24 55 86 
25 72 71 72 21 65 59 83 
90 87 24 62 85 36 33 18 96 
87 26 84 88 92 63 62 50 82 7 

47 
42 48 
10 24 34 
28 72 89 97 
2 12 60 71 81 
8 13 27 48 74 87 
19 24 44 54 55 58 86 
21 25 59 65 71 72 72 83 
18 24 33 36 62 85 87 90 96 
7 26 50 62 63 82 84 87 88 92
```